# Distinct Limit on php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is the script i used.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "merlin";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}    
$time_start = microtime(true);
$sql = "SELECT Distinct host_name FROM report_data limit 5";
$time_end = microtime(true);
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Job Done ";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}   
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "In $time seconds\n";       
$conn->close();
?>
```

OUTPUT:

Error: SELECT Distinct host_name FROM report_data limit 5
In 0 seconds

Comment: Did you check your db connection?

Comment: What error? what's your complete code. please, put some effort in

Comment: You need to add more infos: post the script and the error you're getting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Distinct host_name FROM report_data limit 5";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "host_name: " . $row["host_name"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) ..
```

`mysqli::query` does not return `true`, that's your entire problem. The query works fine. For `SELECT` queries, it returns a *result set*, which I'd suppose you'd want to loop through. Please read the manual for this function: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php